# Where cookies are stored in system?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

If i use `Response.Cookies["test"].Value ="Hi";` where are cookie stored in system?

Can i check `Cookies["test"]` value in my pc because cookies are stored in text format.

I am using VS 2008. Operating system is Windows 7.

I have tried to find in Google but not getting the exact answer. Please help to sort out this problem.

Comment: Click Start, type shell:Cookies to display the cookies folder (be sure hidden files & folders are visible). See: http://www.hevanet.com/tech/win7shortcuts.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IE and Windows keeps cookies here:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
```

Points to the same directory as @Sohnee's does under Windows Visa and newer, but his doesn't under Windows XP and earlier, my - does.

also `Temporary Internet Files` can contain some cookies.

Meanwhile Firefox keeps cookies into SQLite database under profile root:

```
%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%FirefoxProfile%\cookies.sqlite
```

To read the data you need to connect to that database using any SQLite client and execute next query:

```
select value
from moz_cookies
where name = 'test'
```

I did it just now using trial [SQLite Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/download/). And don't forget to close all running Firefoxes before connection attempt.

Comment: can you please explain how to use this tool?

Answer (score 7):

Cookies are stored in the cookies folder on Windows 7. To open the cookies folder, open `run` in Windows and type `shell:cookies`. Also, as suggested above, they might be in Temporary internet files. However, I see that your cookies are not persistent. This means you are not setting any expiration on them. Therefore, they won't be stored on your machine and they will only be part of the browser's memory.

Comment: Good point: without an expiry, it will be a session cookie stored in RAM. Which raises the question, do any browsers have tools that reveal session cookies, or do you have to use a tool like Fiddler to intercept what is received and sent?

Answer (score 1):

> `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Also note, "`Local`" is a hidden folder.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows :**

> C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default.

**For Mac:**

> ~Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies

You can use [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) for access it .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your cookies are stored in your user folder:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
```

You will need to "show" hidden / system files to see them.

Comment: Hey Thanks but I did not find Cookies folder inside Windows folder.

Comment: Okay, you could do a search for folders named "Cookies", it should be in that kind of area. What browser are you using?

Comment: `AppData\Roaming` doesn't exist under Windows XP and earlier

Comment: I have tried to find cookies but not getting any thing.Mozila 3.6.10

Comment: I am using windows 7 live..I got the path %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\

Comment: @abatishchev - the question is explicitly about Windows 7.

Comment: Anyway hard-coding OS-specific directory name is a bad idea, right?

Comment: @abatishchev - the question seems to be in relation to debugging, i.e. checking the cookie that has been programatically created - not about manually getting cookies from the specified directory.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I press `Win+R` and type `shell:Cookies` to open the cookies folder.

it's a hidden folder, the path is

> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies