# Where do browsers store cookies?

Tags: cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where cookies are stored in system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801675/where-cookies-are-stored-in-system)

Hi,

Where are the 'Cookies' stored on our machine ?

1. If I use Mozilla
2. If I use IE
3. Other browsers..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All the Firefox cookies are stored in "cookies.txt" at

`C:\Documents and Settings\Windows login/user name\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\profile folder`

in IE

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<User name>\Local Settings
```

in Chrome

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies
```

Comment: I created a web application in VS 2008 and wrote a code like :-    Response.Cookies["user"].Value = "rauf"; and ran the code using debug option of VS2008. Then I searched the paths specified above and did not find the cookie, Please help me.

Comment: Incorrect. Firefox 3.6.15 stores cookies in an sqlite database, and you have to use a third party tool to extract cookies.txt. Chrome uses  some binary format (possibly sqlite). These paths are also only valid on Windows XP and take no account for Windows Vista/7.

Comment: you need to use cookie editor

Comment: Yeas. I got it. Go to Windows->Start->Run                                                             "C:\Documents and Settings\rauf\Cookies"

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic location, it depends entirely on the browser, and in some cases the version as well (some versions of Firefox stored them in a file called cookies.txt, now I think it is in an sqlite database).

Google is your friend!