# I do not know what is the cookie's path? how to find it?

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
 function setCookie(name, value)
    {
        var times = 30;
        var exp = new Date();
        exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + times * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        document.cookie = name + "=" + encodeURI(value) + ";expires=" + exp.toUTCString() + ";path=/";       
    }
```

"path=/" represents cookie's path is what? and if delete "path=/", cookie's path is what?

Comment: Is it some javascript poem? Regarding path you cannot access it from code

Comment: @Novice, This is js code; I want to find the cookie, where is the cookie? Thanks for your reply

Comment: I want to know where  the cookie file locates

Comment: That's what I am saying friend .While storing cookies by you supply all stuff but when you try to read by using `document.cookie` it will only give  this part `name + "=" + encodeURI(value)` And path does not refer to your system's path but rather path relative to website.for eg. if cooki is set for path like google/mypony then it will be used only on that page

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel know your mean. you mean that js cookie file can not be  found, because it do not store system's path. is this?

Comment: Exactly!.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"path=/"` means

> path is set, you can access cookie `name` anywhere in your
>   application/domain (http://localhost or http://example.com)

`"path=/"` is not set means

> path is not set, then cookie `name` is save just for the directory(also include its child directory)
>   in which current page belongs to, you can't access it on another directory

Check this links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Thank you very much! And I want to know where is the cookie?Could you help me?

Comment: if you not set the path=/,  then by default the cookie belongs to the current page and you can access from the page where the cookie is created

Comment: check this link <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700746/where-do-browsers-store-cookies">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700746/where-do-browsers-store-cookies</a>

Comment: you got the cookie file?