# How cookies stores physically?

Tags: http, cookies

Could help me with clarifying how key - value data of cookies physically stores in browser? 
So, for example "name"="Alex" - where it'll be stored, in shared cookies from other sites? 
Could you shed a light on this, please

Comment: That's two different questions. Please only one question in every question.

Comment: Was updated. First question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where cookies are stored in system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801675/where-cookies-are-stored-in-system)

Answer (score 0):

It is 4KB storage and working per window or tab. It stored in files and location depend on browser.

Check further detail from here : https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en&vid=0-741729026382-1526222962080